# Ошибка при подключении БД. Как решить?

Tags: python, mysql

Вроде почитал документацию, но так и не понял как решить проблему.

Ошибка : sha256_password requires SSL

```py
def connection():
    try :
        conn = connect(host = "localhost",
                user = 'realmi',
                password = '',
                database = 'shop',
                auth_plugin='mysql_native_password')
        c = conn.cursor()
        return c , conn
    except Exception as ex :
            print('плохо')
            print(ex) 
    print('хорошо')
```

Comment: Здравствуйте. Добавьте в ваш вопрос код, в котором возникает данная ошибка.

Comment: @Frehzy добавил

Comment: Из какой библиотеки функция `connect`, и какой версии библиотека?

Comment: @decorator-factory библиотека mysql , вроде последняя версия.

Comment: @Karasmhi Пакет называется `mysql`, `mysql-connector-python`, `PyMySQL` или какой-то другой?

Comment: @decorator-factory  Я использую  : mysql.connector

Comment: Под названием пакета я имел в виду не название импортируемого модуля, а название пакета на PyPI. Какой командой вы устанавливали библиотеку?

Comment: mysql-connector-python